# Logging from log4Cplus to Log4j

Tags: logging, log4j, cross-platform, log4cplus

I would like to use Log4xx (Log4j & log4Cplus) as logging api which runs on a C++ and also on a Java client, which send all logs to a log4j (java) server.

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/SocketAppender.html
A socketappender creates serialized obects, which will transfer them to a server.

Can I resive objects from a log4Cplus Client on a log4j server?

Is there any alternative API?

Thanks folks

Answer (score 0):

The log4cplus' `SocketAppender` is not compatible with log4j's `SocketAppender`. So the only remotely possible option is to use [`Log4jUdpAppender`](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/docs/html/classlog4cplus_1_1Log4jUdpAppender.html). I am not sure if there is a compatible listener in log4j itself. I (think I) have tested Chainsaw and Log2console with this and it worked. There is no TCP transport, yet.